# Working with named credentials

Tags: apex, integration, json

I have a below piece of code that works as expected.

```
 Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest hreq = new HttpRequest();
        hreq.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id='+consumerKey+'&client_secret='+consumerSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password);
        hreq.setMethod('POST');
        
        blob headervalue = Blob.valueOf(username+':'+password);
        
        string authorizationValue = 'BASIC'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headervalue);
        
        hreq.setHeader('Authorization',authorizationValue);
        
        HttpResponse hresp =  h.send(hreq);
        
        system.debug('hresp'+hresp.getBody());
```

in the debug logs I get below JSON which is again as expected

> {"access_token":"SESSION_ID_REMOVED","instance_url":"https://gs650x9-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com","id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D5Y000001M51WUAS/0055Y00000DbbnXQAR","token_type":"Bearer","issued_at":"1613552789028","signature":"qaKXe9mNDKCqoLj7H90E97XKuv/qx6INEyZnMe/7Btw="}

Now instead of doing like above, I want to use named credentials instead.

so I created auth provider, put the consumer key, & the secret then created a named credential added the auth provider and it prompted the login page, logged in accordingly and the status is also authenticated as `<user name>`

So far everything is going good, now it's time to execute the apex code as per the named credential created.

```
Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('callout:myNamedCredentials');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        System.debug('Code '+response.getBody());
```

But now the debug log doesn't return the similar JSON instead I get something like below
[image]

All I need is a session Id from this rest callout so that I can pass the same session Id to make a soap call using Oauth2. Without using named credentials, everything works as expected, can someone please suggest if this is possible with named credentials if yes then how to do the same.

Comment: If you use a named credential you shouldn't do a separate call to get a session id/access token. You should just directly call the endpoint you'd like to call, without the hassle of authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but in my case, I need a session Id because, in the end, I want to make a SOAP call not a rest endpoint call.

Comment: That should still work. Have you seen this question; https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144286/use-named-credentials-with-a-soap-wsdl2apex-class

Comment: Yes, I get an invalid session-id error